# Why does one of my LED flood lights randomly turn on and off?

Tags: lighting

One of my outdoor floodlights stays on for approximately an hour then goes out.The other led floodlight on the same fixture randomly goes on and off also, but not as much. Are the bulbs going bad, or is it something else.

Comment: You've given us very little to work with here. A link to or mention of the product would help, or at least a basic description of the controls at your disposal.

Comment: Did you install the fixtures? Perhaps they are motion-controlled?

Comment: Are the bulbs Feit Electric, Utilitech or cheapie house brand?

Answer (score 1):

Over the last couple of years I have installed hundreds of LED fixtures and relamped Flouresents to LED's every failure I have had has been due to a bad driver. I have some drivers totally fail no light, some fail by reducing the output, and others flicker or strobe. I have pulled each failure apart and none of the LED's have failed each time it has been the driver. On the expensive fixtures I have been able to repair the drivers when not potted but if potted I replace the drivers. There could be other causes but it sounds like the drivers are overheating and shutting down.